Form Submit event listener disabled by Google Password Manager
I am unable to copy/paste code in to here because of the policies of the place I work, but here is the scenario. We are having an issue where a basic "submit" event listener is not working when Google Password Manager autofills in the username and password. If the user just clicks "Sign On" the submit event does not work. But if they click in to the username or password field and then click "sign on" the event works. My actual function name is not "runCode", but for demo purposes..
signonForm.addEventListener('submit', runCode);

function runCode() {
if (obj == undefined) return false
return obj.function()
}

I can put a breakpoint inside the function and watch it run in every other scenario, but like I said above... if the login fields are prefilled and the user does not click in to either field the function does not run at all. Any thoughts on this one?

What steps have you taken to debug this? What are x and obj in the code your have provided? Is the submit button actually disabled or is the submit function erroring?

@mykaf The last paragraph describes their debugging steps: They put a breakpoint in the function, and it's not even running.

When you refer to Google Password Manager, are you talking about something other than the built-in password autofill in Chrome?

@mykaf I edited the code example a bit. We have narrowed it down to the password manager, I was trying to create a minimal version of what was needed to ask the question. But we are checking for the object (obj) to be defined, and if it is.. on submit run a function that is a method of that object. runCode is not working at all in this scenario so my next step in debugging was to come here and see if anyone else had experienced this issue

@barmar yes I am referring to the built in password manager for google chrome

I'm finding this difficult  to believe, as it would undoubtedly affect thousands of websites. If you don't have an event listener, does the form submit normally?

@Barmar the form actually submits with a form action url, so it still will submit and log users in, but this function does not run and the event listener doesn't work. To your point, that is why I'm extremely confused.  Spent a whole day arguing with people that it doesn't make sense, but once I checked it out today,.... its true

I tried to reproduce this at https://dev.bridgebase.com/barmar_test/test.html. It autofills the username and password, and clicking on the submit button runs the event listener. So the problem is something specific to your page or environment.

@barmar thank you I will continue to look in to it
